# Standings Head to Head Tiebreak

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to set up a league for our ping pong table at work. There are 6 guys that play each other once. So everyone plays 5 games and there is always a head to head tiebreaker to decide the rankings. I am trying to come up with a formula that will tiebreak their ranking if it comes to that. I know this is more easily possible in VBA, but I'm trying to see if I can do this with a formula first.

[image: Standings Table]

[image: Match Results]

These are the 2 tables that I have. First the tiebreaker decides based off of differential in points, next is the head to head if it comes to that. It was easy to get to this point, but can't figure out how to find the ones with the same differential and locate their match in the match results table.

My ranking formula is:

```
=RANK(F4,$F$4:$F$9)+SUMPRODUCT(($F$4:$F$9=F4)*(E4<$E$4:$E$9))
```

Comment: are you trying to achieve this all in a single cell or can space off to the side be used to rearrange data do some temporary calc and what not

Comment: On a side note, what row/column in your imaged data above is F4?  ie is the name Andrew in the first table A4?

Comment: B4 is the first name "Andrew". I would prefer to do this in a single cell, but I can use a seperate sheet or other cells if easier.

Comment: SO in this case you are trying to break the tie between Brad and Jesse? and Jeese should be 5 and Brad 6 because Jesse beat brad in game 5 from the bottom of the list.  As an aside was the match list numbered?  And what is the range for the match list since no column row references are visible.

Comment: Ah I apologize, I should have included cell references in my pictures. The match list isn't numbered, but the matches themselves are in the range L3:P17. Names and amounts may change, but there should only be this many games played.

Comment: So in this case you only have two people that are tied and therefore need a head to head tie breaker for them.   Is it possible to get a three way tie where  A beat B and B beat C and C beat A?

Comment: Yes, then differential is used after the head to head result. I am able to get this part of the tiebreaker working easily, just can't figure out the head to head aspect.

Comment: what I meant to say in previous comment is if the differentials are also tied.  So you wind up with a three way tie where each player has beaten another player in the tie, and their point differentials are the same.  if you go through your match list ans set the scores so that every time brad, jesse, and Kamari play they score 0 points in the match.  now change it so that when Jesse play Brad, brad wins with 11 points, Jesse still 0.  When Brad plays Kamari, Kamari wins 11 to 0, when Kamari plays Jesse, Jesse win 11 to 0.  of Brad, Jesse, and Kamari who is top and who is bottom?

Comment: If it gets that far, then there will be a play in game to figure out the seeding for those. It doesn't happen often, almost never, but that will be played out if they are all tied.

Comment: I must admit that I enjoy solving these *rank ties* problems but I hate typing out sample data even more.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem well, you need to find a formula that will determine if two players have the same ranking after the set of games.
On easy way to find this is to count how many players have the same rank.
With countif() function you can find this out.
For each cell from G4 to G9, you calculate countif($G$4:$G$9,Gx) in column H for example.
The lines with a count of 2 (or more) will be the one to tie break.

With this you can factor everything in the same cell and rely only on formulas to handle the tie break case

[Excel Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqgnN.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not as easy as you would think with formulas. I ended up using VBA to come up with a solution, a lot easier to come up with the logic. But comparing the specific game in question to find the head to head matchup is not easily done with a formula, if at all.